# UWP App - InkCanvas and InkToolbar in HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, uwp, windows-10-universal

Can the new `InkCanvas` and `InkToolbar` (see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn858535)) be used in Windows 10 UWP HTML5/JS apps? I see only C#, C++, and VB tabs in the documentation.

This is in the documentation under XAML controls, which to my understanding is **not** part of the HTML support. Is there an alternative/complementary HTML5/JS tool set for these components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `InkCanvas` and `InkToolbar` are currently not supported in UWP HTML5/JS. For HTML5/JS, you can use [this official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Ink) as reference. There you'll see the sample uses a regular `<canvas>` and a `WinJS.UI.ToolBar`.

Comment: It's too bad there isn't an alternative for HTML/JS yet. Ink support is a valuable addition to the platform.