# PWA InkCanvas save strokes as svg in javascript

Tags: svg, canvas, progressive-web-apps, inkcanvas

I need to use InkCanvas in my web application using javascript (angular), is it possible to save InkCanvas as a SVG using javascript (or convert InCanvas to canvas)? i see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107362/uwp-inkcanvas-save-stokes-as-svg), but it seems it works for C#, i need a way to do it in javascript!

Answer (score 1):

I think [InkCanvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas(v=vs.110).aspx) is only supported in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) for Windows10. This is confirmed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330073/6577242).

Comment: Thanks for attention, is that any way to convert InkCanvas to Canvas? and then save canvas as SVG (with existing tools) @noogui

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Webassembly](https://webassembly.org/) to run C# code in web browser using some JS helpers. [Here is a post explaining the same.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/blazor-running-c-sharp-on-browser-using-web-assembly/)

You can try this with the c# code that you are interested in. Compatibility depended. These are relatively new features and only way to know is to try.